# Binding visibility of rectangle control to button's isEnabled property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have several buttons, each implemented as a `UserControl`, on a screen, and only 1 will be enabled at a time. Now there is a sidebar type `Rectangle` next to all buttons in the `UserControl`, which should only be visible for 1 button, whichever is enabled. Tried several bindings to control the visibility of the rectangle with `IsEnabled`, but failed. Also have a visibility converter ready. Here's my code:

```
<Grid>
   <Button Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonStyle}" x:Name="BtnUC">
       <Button.Content>
           <Grid>
               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                   <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
                   <ColumnDefinition/>
               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

               <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="LightGray" Margin="-4,0,0,0">
                   
               </Rectangle>
               <Viewbox ....
               </Viewbox>
           </Grid>

       </Button.Content>
   </Button>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an instance of a [`BooleanToVisibilityConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Controls.BooleanToVisibilityConverter);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) converter in any resources in scope.

```
<Window.Resources>
   <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Then bind the [`Visibility`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.visibility?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) of the rectangle to the `IsEnabled` property  of your button by referring to it using the [element name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.elementname?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) `BtnUC`. By specifying the  converter, `true` will be converted to [`Visible`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.visibility?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) and `false` to `Collapsed`.

```
<Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="LightGray" Margin="-4,0,0,0"
           Visibility="{Binding IsEnabled, ElementName=BtnUC, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Alternatively, if there is no button name, refer to the parent `Button` via [`RelativeSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource?view=windowsdesktop-6.0).

```
<Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="LightGray" Margin="-4,0,0,0"
           Visibility="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Style` with a `DataTrigger` that sets the `Visibility` property of the `Rectangle` based on the value of the `IsEnabled` property of the `Button`:

```
<Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="LightGray" Margin="-4,0,0,0">
    <Rectangle.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Rectangle.Style>
</Rectangle>
```